# How to reference Cloudformation Ressources in a new Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reference, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have two Cloudformation files and I want to reference already created Ressources from one template, in another template. For Example: In the first one I create an ECS Cluster. In the second one I want to reference this cluster and build a Service in it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to [exporting stack output values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) from the first template. Presumably this would be ECS Cluster name and/or its arn:

```
MyCluster:
   Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
   Properties: 
    #....

Outputs:
  MyClusterName:
     Value: !Ref MyCluster
     Export:
        Name: ECSClusterName
```

Then in the second template you would use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to reference the exported output:

```
MyESSService:
   Type: AWS::ECS::Service
   Properties: 
     Cluster: !ImportValue ECSClusterName
```